# HTC Vive display is blurry

Tags: steam-vr, vive

I recently bought a HTC Vive and on all of my games it looks blurry. I asked a friend who also has a Vive on what I could do, he said change the resolution percentage in Steam VR. I tried this and nothing worked, I have also tried to adjust the headset lenses (backwards and forwards and side to side) but that doesn't work either. I know VR headsets are not supposed to have amazing picture quality but it is really quite bad when I am playing, especially when I am playing pavlov, I can barely see enemies that are 10m+ from me. If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be much appreciated if you could let me know :) Thanks.

Comment: You mean to say you fiddled with both the IPD and lens distance knobs and didn't find the "sweetspot"? Do you wear glasses with your vive?

Comment: The lenses can also get greasy. Make sure they're clean.

Comment: Do you have your headset adjusted properly? You should be looking directly through the center of the lenses, if you are off axis the display gets pretty blurry pretty quick.
Also, while cleaning be careful not to scratch the lenses, any scratches will cause issues going forward.

Comment: @Xander Yep I have adjusted the lens using the distance knobs and its still blurry, no I don not wear glasses with the Vive.

Comment: @RoijanEskor The headset is brand new so I didn't think I would have to clean the lenses so soon, I'll give it a go though, thanks.

Comment: @Malco I believe I have adjusted the headset correctly, when I am using the headset, I am looking through the center. I have also not cleaned the lenses yet because the headset is very new.

Comment: @Dom Dumb question but might as well cover all the bases, but is there an anti scratch film on the lenses that you can pull off?

Comment: @Malco I'm pretty sure that there wasn't one on it, I also thought that could have been the problem but when I checked I was unable to peel anything off.

Comment: @DomEvans Hmmm, I'm not sure what it could be. Could you provide some photos of your HMD as well as screenshots from the SteamVR mirror (not the window that might pop-up for some games but the actual HMD display mirror). The only other thing I can think of is maybe your super sampling is messed up?